# How to Customize ValidationException Response in Lumen?

Tags: php, lumen

I develop an REST API using Lumen. I thought using `details` key inside JSON object is convenient to show errors. See the response:

```
{"detail": "Something bad happened."}
```

Lumen has validation that you can call inside a controller as in `$this->validate(["foo" => "required", "bar" => "required"})`. If I do not set `foo` value in the request body, the server naturally responds:

```
{
    "foo": [
        "The foo field is required."
    ]
}
```

However, I also want these to be inside `details` key so that it would be convenient for consumer. See the desired repsonse:

```
{
    "details": {
        "foo": [
            "The foo field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this, if so, how?

### Further Investigation

As [Validation section in Lumen documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) states:

> Should validation fail, the $this->validate helper **will throw Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException** with embedded JSON response that includes all relevant error messages.

That means somehow I need to extend `ValidationException`, but I still do not have any idea about how to trigger my `CustomValidationException` in `$this->validate` method.

---

### Environment

- PHP 7.3.5
- Lumen 5.8

Answer (score 4):

In your **App/Exception/Handler** class, add these lines:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

...

public function render($request, Throwable $exception) {
    ...

    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        return response()->json([
                    'details' => $exception->errors(),
        ], 422);
    }


    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

And you still get the translated messages. Tested in Lumen 7.0.

Comment: _Thank_you_ ! :) I've been trying for a couple of hours now to understand why `$this->validate($request, ..` works fine, but not `Validator::make([..], ..`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the result of $this->validate() to a variable and use that variable in your json response according to your choice.
Like following:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'foo' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['details'=> $validator->errors()->first() ], 400);
        }
```

**400 here is json response. You may use it or not**